# Upgrade problem- 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

I tried to upgrade to 12.04 using the update manager in 11.10. It opens up a dialog which says downloading upgrade tools and just closes. Anyways to upgrade? Or a working solution to this problem? I would like to upgrade internally therefore keeping all of my files instead of installing a new version of Ubuntu entirely. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot upgrade using the Update Manager, download the ISO file from the Ubuntu website. Make a Live USB or CD/DVD, then boot using the download media. During the installation, you can either upgrade or do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my advice. If you want to keep all your files, there is the way green7 listed by downloading the new iso and using a live install, however if you look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades/) This tells you how to do a network upgrade properly and should be of some help. If not I think green7's answer is what you'll want to work on.

Here's what the link says: Network Upgrade for Ubuntu Desktops 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS (Recommended)

Note that the page under https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_to_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS says: "It is generally recommended that users of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS wait until the first point release, due in August, before upgrading." Follow the instructions there if you want to upgrade earlier since the following instructions will probably not work until then.

You can easily upgrade over the network with the following procedure.

Open the Update Manager application from the System → Administration menu.

In Update Manager, click the Settings... button, and enter your password to start the Software Sources application.

Select the sub menu Updates from the Software Sources application.

Check the "Release upgrade - Show new distribution releases" drop down to make sure "Long term support releases only" is selected, and change it if otherwise.
Close the Software Sources application and return to Update Manager.
In Update Manager, click the Check button to check for new updates.

If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release.

Click Upgrade. 
Follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt=normal;

Followed by: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Source: [Howto: Upgrade To Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin From 10.04, 11.04, 11.10 | Desktop & Server](http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-1004-1010-1104-to-ubuntu-1110-oneiric-ocelot-desktop-a-server/)